# Como contar palabras en DART

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart

este lenguaje me tiene sufriendo, no encuentro como hacerlo. Alguien tiene idea de como contar las palabras en DART o como contar espacios vacios?

```
string micadena ="Hola mundo soy Aldahir";
int longitud = " ".allmatches(micadena).lenght;

return longitud;
```

Tengo esto, esto me cuenta el nro de letras especificas ej, a, b, c ,d y asi... pero lo que quiero es contar los espacios para saber el numero de palabras, o si hay alguna otra funcion para saber el numero de palabras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar el método `split` de `String`, lo que hace es dividir la cadena de acuerdo al `String` que le pases.

```dart
  String micadena ="Hola mundo soy Aldahir";
  int longitud =  micadena.split(' ').length;
  print('Palabras: $longitud');
  //Resultado 4
```

El problema es que te podría dar resultados inesperados si hay más de un espacio entre las palabras.

```dart
  String micadena ="Hola mundo soy  Aldahir";
  int longitud =  micadena.split(' ').length;
  print('Palabras: $longitud');
  //Resultado 5
```

Si no quieres tener problemas, podrías usar una expresión regular:

```dart
  String micadena ="Hola mundo soy  Aldahir";
  final regExp = RegExp(r"\w+(\'\w+)?");
  int longitud = regExp.allMatches(micadena).length;
  print('Palabras: $longitud');
  //Resultado 4
```

Con eso no tendrás errores.